# How to add customized path routes in Nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Here is my app pages like

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/products/
https://example.com/products/1
https://example.com/blogs/
https://example.com/blogs/1
...
```

and directorys are like below

```
pages
> products
  > index.vue
  > [id].vue
> blogs
  > index.vue
  > [id].vue
...
```

And now I got the task to create pages like below

```
https://example.com/g/          => (exactry same as https://example.com/)
https://example.com/g/products/ => (exactry same as https://example.com/products/)
https://example.com/g/products/1/ => (exactry same as https://example.com/products/1/)
...
```

It is hard to copy all pages under 'g' directory and I don't want to duplicate codes.

Is there any solution?

(I can not redirect to original pages. Can not change url.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can extend the vue-router routes in Nuxt 3 (see this message on nuxt github repository, issue [#12823](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/12823#issuecomment-1397279500)).

It uses a build time hook called `pages:extend` (see the list of [build hooks](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/advanced/hooks#nuxt-hooks-build-time)).
Its only parameter is the already registered routes (from the `/pages` folder). So you can use it to duplicate the route configuration.

```js
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { createCommonJS } from 'mlly'
const { __dirname } = createCommonJS(import.meta.url)

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  hooks: {
    'pages:extend'(pages) {
      // Add fixed page
      pages.push({
        name: 'testAbout',
        path: '/test/about',
        file: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/about.vue'),
      });

      // Get all pages you want to duplicate with a `/g` prefix route path
      const pagesToDuplicate = pages.filter(page => page.path === '/' || page.path.startsWith('/products' || page.path.startsWith('/blog')));
      pagesToDuplicate.forEach(page => {
        pages.push({
          ...page,
          path: `/g${page.path}`,
          name: `g-${page.name}`,
        });
      });
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Your answer gave me hint to solve. your code override existing routing because of same name available in pages. so it should be like below code.

``` js
pagesToDuplicate.forEach(page => {
  pages.push({
    ...page,
    path: `/g${page.path}`,
    name: `g-${page.name}`
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated my anwser with the route name.

Answer (score -1):

I would use [middleware](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware) for that:

Create `/middleware/redirect.global.ts` with:

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to) => {
  if (to.path.startsWith('/g/')) {
    return navigateTo(to.path.replace('/g',''))
  }
})
```

This will run before each routing, check the target path, and if it sees the new subdirectory in the path, it will just extract it and re-route to original page structure.

**Attention:** Make sure the altered route is absolute - it has to start with `/`, otherwise you'll end up in an infinite navigaion loop.

Comment: OP explicitely said he doesn't want a redirection. He wants both routes to live together.